# Java 8 update 91 plugin connects to get all classes

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

When I installed Java 8 update 91 JRE in my computer I noticed that all my JNLP applications where slower. Console displays this for each class used by my application:

```
network: No se ha encontrado la entrada de caché [URL: https://sleipnir5.accv.es:8444/System/Library/Java/es/accv/arangi/base/exception/device/CipherException.class, versión: null]
network: Conectando https://sleipnir5.accv.es:8444/System/Library/Java/es/accv/arangi/base/exception/device/CipherException.class con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://sleipnir5.accv.es:8444 con proxy=DIRECT
```

In server logs I check that in fact Java client requests for all classes in path: /System/Library/Java/<package + class>.

I don't know how resolve this situation. It hasn't sense that Java client requests class by class to server instead download and work with jar files.

My JNLP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="https://sleipnir5.accv.es:8444/npsc/jnlp/npsc">
    <information>
        <title>Generacion certificado NPSC</title>
        <vendor>Agencia de Tecnología y Certificación Electrónica</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.accv.es" />
        <description>Generacion certificado NPSC</description>
    </information>
    <offline-allowed />
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="npsc-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="quaqua.jar"/>
        <jar href="arangi-1.4.4.jar" />
        <jar href="arangi_base-1.4.4.jar" />
        <jar href="MITyCLibAPI-1.0.4_1.jar"/>
        <jar href="MITyCLibTSA-1.0.4_1.jar"/>
        <jar href="MITyCLibXADES-1.0.4_1.jar"/>
        <jar href="xmlsec-1.4.2-ADSI-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="axis-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="axis-saaj-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="commons-discovery-0.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="iaikPkcs11Wrapper-1.2.17.jar"/>
        <jar href="ldap-1.0.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="log4j-1.2.13.jar"/>
        <extension name="Bouncy Castle" href="npsc_bouncy.jnlp"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="es.accv.npsc.jnlp.NPSCJnlp" width="1" height="1">
        <argument>48</argument>
        <argument>7790</argument>
        <argument>xxx</argument>
        <argument>es</argument>
        <argument>aplicacion</argument>
        <argument>22585858X</argument>
        <argument>https://sleipnir5.accv.es:8444/npsc/services/NpscWS</argument>
    </application-desc>
    <update check="background" />
</jnlp>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I fix it. A jar had in his manifest.mf:

```
Class-Path: swing-layout.jar /System/Library/Java/
```

In Java 8 update 91 this implies that plugin connects to URL <domain>/System/Library/Java to find classes it needs.